# How do you change the ruler's background in vim?

Tags: vim, background

[image: Vim Ruler's Background]

How do I change the background color of vim's ruler? Currently, I am using this colorscheme: https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim. The ruler doesn't have a distinct background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ruler" is something else (`:help ruler`), what you want is the `LineNr` highlight group which is defined at multiple locations in your colorscheme:

- https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim#L210
- https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim#L217
- https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim#L320
- https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim#L336
- https://github.com/thayerwilliams/vimbrant/blob/master/vimbrant.vim#L513

Answer (score 3):

Answering the title question, which brought me here.

The item %#HighlightGroup# will set the highlight group for the rest of the ruler, until you change it with another %#...#. Check `:highlight` to see all the hl groups. Here is a simple example of a ruler with multiple color groups:

```
:set rulerformat=%38(%#TabLine#\ %-t\ %m\ %#MatchParen#\ %12(%l:%c%V%)\ %k\ %4p%%%)
```